# Calling Compile() on Expression<T> multiple times and caching

Tags: caching, lambda, c#-3.0, compilation, expression-trees

I haven't found any information on MSDN regarding this problem.

If we create an `Expression<Func<T>>` and call `Compile()` on it does CLR cache compiled results, so any subsequent calls of `Compile()` on the same expression wouldn't have much impact because CLR would return previously compiled `Func<T>` from internal memory cache?

AFAIK lambda expressions are immutable, so internal caching would actually make sense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258864/when-an-expressiont-is-compiled-is-it-implicitly-cached

Comment: Thanks Snowbear. I voted my own question to be closed as a duplicate. :) Never done that before. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it simply returns a delegate to the compiled version.  The expression itself is not affected.

```
Expression<Func<T>> expression = ...;
Func<T> compiled = expression.Compile();
T value = compiled();
```

Comment: @Robert It should be pretty easy to cache the reference to the returned delegate.

Comment: I know I know. The only *issue* is that I will have to create a separate class where I'll hold expression itself and compiled delegate reference, because I will be using it multiple times. Both of them. If compiled delegate would be cached I could simply use `Expression<T>` and avoid a custom class. Less code is always better from the maintainability point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of necromancy here in the form of a linqpad script. This will cache the compiled value in a Weak table

```
void Main()
{
    Expression<Func<string>> expression = () => "hello";
    expression.ExecuteWithCachedCompile().Dump(); //ta-da!
}
static class CachedCompileExtension
{
    private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<object, object> props = new ConditionalWeakTable<object, object>();

    public static T ExecuteWithCachedCompile<T>(this Expression<Func<T>> key)
    { 
        var func = (Func<T>) props.GetValue(key, (k) => key.Compile());       
        return func();
    } 
}
```