# C# How to turn <T> and Expression<Func<T, string>> selector into T.Select( selector)?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Below is how far I made it.  I need to send `Expression<Func<T, string>>` as the parameter instead of `Func<T,string>` to the Get function, and still have Select() work.  Is this easily possible?  This is formatted for [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

```
void Main()
{
    // Setup sample data in wholelist
    var wholelist = new List<Example>();
    for (var a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {   var t = new Example { id = a.ToString(), name = a.ToString() };
        wholelist.Add(t);
    }

    // Do the real work
    var names = Get<Example>( wholelist, p => p.name );
    // LinqPad shows content
    names.Dump();
}

public class Example
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public static List<string> 
    Get<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> selector)
{    
    var list = source.Select<T,string>(selector).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

The why is because we have a lot of functions already calling this one with `Expression<Func<T,string>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried expression.Compile?

```
public static List<string> Get<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector)
{
    var list = source.Select<T, string>(selector.Compile()).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: Glad it worked. Love the name, btw.
If this method is hit often, it may be worth looking into temporarily caching the result of Compile. Here's a discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258864/when-an-expressiont-is-compiled-is-it-implicitly-cached